# Webhook response in Mailgun returns a forbidden code

Tags: php, laravel, webhooks, mailgun, laravel-10

I have configured a test web hook in Mailgun to send to PipeDream RequestBin.  When I test the web hook it works fine, gives a response, gets 200 back.

I have now changed the endpoint to be my own PHP website (written in Laravel 10, but not using the default Mailgun Laravel system).  At this point the web hook is pointing to a URL that is setup as a 'POST' in web routing, that sends it to a controller that should do nothing but return an HTTP 200 Status.  I have included the URL in the CSRF exclusion array in middleware.

If I 'POST' data from another page, it works fine.  If I test the web hook I am getting the following response on the Mailgun web hook test page:

```
Response: <html><body><h1>403 Forbidden</h1>
Request forbidden by administrative rules.
</body></html>
```

I am assuming the above 403 response is coming back from my server, but I cannot understand why. Can anyone tell me what I am missing please, or point me in the right direction?  I have been playing with this for the past five hours and getting no where.

Comment: "*I am assuming the above 403 response is coming back from my server*" - have you checked that, eg Laravel and web server logs? "*If I 'POST' data from another page, it works fine*" - just to be clear, do you mean eg a form on another page on your site, posting to the same URL, works OK?  Do you have any kind of authentication, basic htauth, login, API auth involved?

Comment: Laravel logs are not showing anything unusual, but I’ll check the server logs in the morning. Yes another form doing a POST action is fine. No authentication at all, it’s just a basic page to prove things work, no setup authentication within Laravel at all. The page I am POSTing to idles not even read what’s been posted, it should just return 200. My thought being keep it as simple as possible so we have a working base line.

Comment: Interestingly there's no 403 entries in the server logs, so maybe it's not coming from my server.  It makes me wonder if the domain for the web hook needs to be the same as the registered mailgun domain - but then having said that it works ok with 'POST' test websites such as RequestBin?

Comment: Mailgun are now looking into the matter.